# Проверка настроек приложения Android

Tags: android, java

Как сделать проверку приложения: если в настройках есть пункт `firstrun = 1`, то запускать допустим `activityMain`, а если `firstrun = 0`, запускать `FirstRunActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял.

```
if(firstrun==1){Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityMain.class);
           startActivity(intent);}
else {Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstRunActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);}
```

не забудь подключить библиотеку
import android.content.Intent;

Comment: красивее стартовать, один раз - после отпределения интента, ну и не совсем красиво создавать активити, которая будет что-то решать, а потом запускать другие, лучше подставлять динамически

Comment: Мне нужно как-то разобратся с настройками приложения в Android. Тоесть не обычная переменная, а 'ячейка' в настройках. Вот что мне нужно

Comment: А как сделать через настройки это? (конфиг с настройками приложения, чтобы там был firstrun)

Comment: sharedpreferences

Comment: Используйте `SharedPreferences` [пример тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 0):

Все как обычно, только в методе `onCreate()` проверяешь настройку и подставляешь или старуешь нужное активити